# Visual basic create graphics form picturebox then draw shapes

Tags: vb.net

On form load event I create graphics from an empty (no image) picturebox called PB_Pixel_Layout.

```
Private Sub Main_From_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Pixel_Graphics = PB_Pixel_Layout.CreateGraphics

End Sub
```

I then draw a bunch of filled ellipses through the SetPixel(). The ellipses get drawn on the picturebox but takes 2 cycles of the the SetPixel() to show. There is also a double window image when the program starts the causes a lag and not sure what is causing the problem but I assume I have not setup the graphics correctly. I tried to run by creating a bitmap at run time instead of using a picturebox and it worked fine so the issue is narrowed down to the create graphics from picturebox. I also tried to loading an image to the picturebox properties but did not make a difference.

```
 Private Sub SetPixel_Grid_Bitmap()

    Pen_Grid = New Pen(Color.Gray)

    Selected_Pen = New Pen(Color.Yellow)

    'draw 
    For Col = 0 To intColumnCount

        For Row = 0 To intRowCount

            B_Color = Color.FromArgb(intPatternColorsRed(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank)), intPatternColorsGreen(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank)), intPatternColorsBlue(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank)))
            Brush_B = New SolidBrush(B_Color)

            '// Grid
            Pixel_Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pen_Grid, StartLocation.X + (Col * (intScale + 6)), StartLocation.Y + (Row * (intScale + 6)), intScale, intScale)

            '// Fill with color
            Pixel_Graphics.FillEllipse(Brush_B, StartLocation.X + (Col * (intScale + 6)) + 2, StartLocation.Y + (Row * (intScale + 6)) + 2, intScale - 4, intScale - 4)
            '// Selected
            If ArrPixelData_Array(intCounter)(P_Selected) = 1 Then
                Pixel_Graphics.DrawEllipse(Selected_Pen, StartLocation.X + (Col * (intScale + 6)), StartLocation.Y + (Row * (intScale + 6)), intScale, intScale)

            End If


            intCounter = intCounter + 1

        Next Row

    Next Col
End Sub
```

Here is the update

```
Public Sub RefreshDrawing()
    bm = New Bitmap(PB_Pixel_Layout.Width, PB_Pixel_Layout.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BB)
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

    End Using

    PB_Pixel_Layout.Image = bm        ' assign drawn bitmap to picturebox
End Sub
```

Comment: "so the issue is narrowed down to the create graphics from picturebox"  100% correct.  Do not use `CreateGraphics()` as that will give you a **temporary** surface that will get erased whenever the PictureBox repaints itself (which happens more often than you think).  Instead, handle the **Paint() Event**  of the PictureBox and draw on the Graphics supplied to you in that event via `e.Graphics`.

Comment: Also, whenever you create a Pen or Brush, you nee to call Dispose() against when done with it.  It's better to create those in a `using` block so they get disposed of when the block exits...

Comment: I added PB_Pixel_Layout_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PB_Pixel_Layout.Paint Do I put the draw ellipes inside or does the drawellipe trigger the paint event. I am a little confused how to handle the draw.

Comment: Either move your draw ellipse code into the Paint() event, or make SetPixel_Grid_Bitmap() receive a Graphics and pass it e.Graphics from the Paint() event (changing the code in either case to use supplied graphics).

Comment: Check this out for an example: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?426684. Basically, you store the data that represents the drawing in fields and, when you want to change the drawing, you update those fields and then call `Invalidate` on the control.  That will raise the `Paint` event and, in the handler, you read the fields and use `e.Graphics` to draw what it represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to declare a global bitmap

```
Dim bm As Bitmap
```

And create a refresh function like (just a general suggestion):

```
Public Sub RefreshDrawing() 
    bm = New Bitmap(Me.Drawing.Width, Me.Drawing.Height)
    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
        Dim r as New RectangleF (200, 100, 400, 300)
        g.FillEllipse(pDrwStyle.dstBrush, r)                 ' draw inside points (area)
        g.DrawEllipse(pDrwStyle.dstPen, Rectangle.Round(r))  ' draw ellipse border
    End Using

    Me.PictureBox1.Image = bm          ' assign drawn bitmap to picturebox
End Sub
```

And in you load event (and perhaps a Refresh button) put simply:

```
Call RefreshDrawing()
```

This is very *fast* and reliable way of drawing graphics.

I would suggest not to use Paint event. Only for temporary drawing, such as drawing in MouseMove mode and such.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I could not get the first samples to run. In the drawing Refresh() do I use create a new g, or use the same Pixel_Graphics. I have updaed post with new code

Comment: `I would suggest not to use Paint event.`  You can do this either way.

Comment: @LasrTech: Yes, that is certainly possible, I just suggested one of the two ways. In my experience there's a notable difference in performance and implementation effort. I respect your opinion if you think differently, especially because I see your valued posts here on SO.

Comment: @Bobby I'm sorry, I made a typo in declaration (`Img` instead `bm`, you can virtually choose one or other - image or bitmap) and a syntax error in `Using g`. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an Alternate suggestion, you could draw it all to a buffer then render that when required.

Like this:

```
 Dim myContext As New BufferedGraphicsContext
 Dim mybuff As System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics
```

(As Globals)

Then add this* before you start drawing anything.

```
        mybuff = myContext.Allocate(picturebox1.CreateGraphics, rectangle)
        mybuff.Graphics.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver
        mybuff.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.AssumeLinear
        mybuff.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None
        mybuff.Graphics.InterpolationMode = CType(Drawing2D.QualityMode.Low, Drawing2D.InterpolationMode)
        mybuff.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.None
```

*Only first line is required the rest is an example custom configuration.
rectangle is the size of your buffer, it needs to be at least as large as the images destination (picturebox1)

To draw into the buffer just type mybuff.Graphics...
eg.

```
mybuff.Graphics.FillRectangle(colbrush,50,50, 4, 4)
mybuff.Graphics.FillEllipse(colbrush, 100, 100, 50, 30)
...
```

When done building the image it needs to be rendered/painted onto the target (picturebox1) like so:

```
mybuff.Render
```

The render does not need to come directly after the drawing it can be called from anywhere in your code. So its up to you when it is painted and how often.

Also doing it like this is much faster than drawing directly to a target.

Lastly dispose of my buff and mycontext when you are done with them.

[EDIT]
Forgot to mention that you can also render the buffer to other targets like so:

```
Mybuff.Render(picturebox2.CreateGraphics)
Mybuff.Render(picturebox47.CreateGraphics)
```